# Compiler's optimization on initializer_list's assignment make program core dump?

Tags: c++

The following code works fine, if I don't open any compiler optimization. However, the it will core dump if I compile it with optimization, i.e. `-O2`

```
string key = "hi";
auto il = {"get", key.c_str(), "ha"};

printf("%p\n", *(il.begin() + 1));   // the address of the second element is normal.

for (const auto &ele : il)
    cout << ele << endl;      // output is normal.

il = {"get", key.c_str()};    // <-- assignment

printf("%p\n", *(il.begin() + 1));  // now, the address is ABNORMAL!!!

for (const auto &ele : il)
    cout << ele << endl;     // <-- output is ABNORMAL.
```

It seems that the compiler optimizes the assignment to initializer_list, and makes it invalid. I've test the code with multiple `CLANG` and `GCC` versions, and it has the same behavior.

My question is:

1. Is it valid to assign an initializer_list?
2. If it's valid, what might the compiler do to make the assignment broke the initializer_list?

**UPDATE**:

Even if I don't dereference `il.begin`, i.e. comment `printf("%p\n", *(il.begin() + 1));`, after assigning the initializer_list, I cannot output it correctly. So it's invalid to call `il = {"get", key.c_str()};`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code as *undefined behaviour* because you try to dereference `il.begin()` which is not valid anymore:

> An object of type `initializer_­list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`.
>   [ *Note:* A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length would be obvious representations for `initializer_­list`.
>   `initializer_­list` is used to implement initializer lists as specified in [[dcl.init.list]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list).
>   Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements.
>   — *end note*
>    ]

It is valid to assign a an `initializer_list`, but in order to access elements, the original `initializer_list` must still exists, e.g.:

```
auto il1 = {1, 2, 3};
std::initializer_list<int> il2;
il2 = il1; // ok because il1 still exists
```

In your case, `{"get", key.c_str()}` is a temporary, so its lifetime ends after the following statement:

```
il = {"get", key.c_str()};
```

Accessing `il.begin()` is valid, but dereferencing it is UB.

Comment: So it's invalid to call `il = {"get", key.c_str()};`? Even if I don't dereference `il.begin()`,  I cannot output the `il` anymore, i.e. the second for loop cannot output correctly.

Comment: @for_stack `il = {"get", key.c_str()};` is not invalid (UB), but accessing any elements of the `initializer_list` is. Within the `for` loop, there is an hidden derefencement which is why the output fails.